# TPL DataFlow Queue with Postponement

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, dataflow, tpl-dataflow

I am processing a queue concurrently using an `ActionBlock`.

The one catch here is that when processing an item in the queue, I may want to wait until a dependency is satisfied by the processing of another item in the queue.

I think I should be able to do this with the *TPL DataFlow* library with linking, postponement and release of postponement but I'm not sure what constructs to use.

In pseudocode:

```
public class Item 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> DependsOn = new List<string>();
}

ActionBlock<Item> block = null;
var block = new ActionBlock<Item>(o => {
    if (!HasActionBlockProcessedAllDependencies(o.DependsOn)) 
    {
       // enqueue a callback when ALL dependencies have been completed
    } 
    else 
    {
        DoWork(o);
    }
},
new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { 
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = resourceProcessorOptions.MaximumProviderConcurrency
});

var items = new[] 
{
    new Item { Name = "Apple", DependsOn = { "Pear" } },
    new Item { Name = "Pear" }
}
```

Comment: So you don't want to process an item unless other items it depends on has been processed ?

Comment: Yes - and I want to re-enque the Item once all of its dependencies have been satisfied in the most efficient way possible.

Comment: Is this in a larger pipeline? The reason I ask is because there is little solved with DataFlow here. Though not impossible, it seems like you just want to keep a dictionary of dependencies with the dependents, and when you process a dependency, post their dependents

Comment: yes, this is a large pipeline, and I want to be processing 10 items at a time

Comment: Linking wont really help you here. There are a couple of approaches, the more convoluted approach is to create a custom block based on a dictionary of queues. however it might just be easier to not post to the first block unless the has been processed, with a similar structure as to whats been explained

Comment: but then I'm blocking other items (that potentially DONT have dependencies) in the queue from processing while waiting for dependencies to finish

Comment: In either of those situation, nothing is blocking anything, only storing items that are dependent. the pipeline or any solution would process as normal, items for which are not dependent, are a dependency, or have a dependency already processed

Comment: but what is it doing while it's waiting for the dependency to be satisfied?

Comment: processing other jobs as they come in

Comment: but I have a max concurrency of 10...so if I have 10 waiting for dependencies, I will deadlock since no threads will be available

Comment: Buffering something is not blocking or using a thread.... ergo max degrees of parallelism is not relevant

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by buffering...can you clarify with an example?

Comment: What should happen in case of circular dependencies? For example A depends on B, and B depends on A?

Comment: Those don’t exist

Comment: Do you have a recommendation?

Comment: @Jeff you can combine the output from different blocks with [JoinBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-use-joinblock-to-read-data-from-multiple-sources) or BatchJoinBlock. You'll have to convert your blocks to TransformBlocks though that are linked to a JoinBlock. A JoinBlock will wait for a message from each of each sources and then publish a combined message.

Comment: But a JoinBlock is strongly typed - my DependsOn is a list of Type - can I make a JoinBlock with dynamic dependency types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this will be helpful to you, but here is a custom `DependencyTransformBlock` class that knows about the dependencies between the items it receives, and processes each one only after its dependencies have been successfully processed. This custom block supports all the built-in functionality of a normal [`TransformBlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.transformblock-2), except from the [`EnsureOrdered`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblockoptions.ensureordered) option.

The constructors of this class accept a `Func<TInput, TKey>` lambda for retrieving the key of each item, and a `Func<TInput, IReadOnlyCollection<TKey>>` lambda for retrieving its dependencies. The keys are expected to be unique. In case a duplicate key is found, the block will complete with failure.

In case of circular dependencies between items, the affected items will remain unprocessed. The property `TInput[] Unprocessed` allows to retrieve the unprocessed items after the completion of the block. An item can also remain unprocessed in case any of its dependencies is not supplied.

```
public class DependencyTransformBlock<TInput, TKey, TOutput> :
    ITargetBlock<TInput>, ISourceBlock<TOutput>
{
    private readonly ITargetBlock<TInput> _inputBlock;
    private readonly IPropagatorBlock<Item, TOutput> _transformBlock;

    private readonly object _locker = new object();
    private readonly Dictionary<TKey, Item> _items;

    private int _pendingCount = 1;
    // The initial 1 represents the completion of the _inputBlock

    private class Item
    {
        public TKey Key;
        public TInput Input;
        public bool HasInput;
        public bool IsCompleted;
        public HashSet<Item> Dependencies;
        public HashSet<Item> Dependents;

        public Item(TKey key) => Key = key;
    }

    public DependencyTransformBlock(
        Func<TInput, Task<TOutput>> transform,
        Func<TInput, TKey> keySelector,
        Func<TInput, IReadOnlyCollection<TKey>> dependenciesSelector,
        ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions dataflowBlockOptions = null,
        IEqualityComparer<TKey> keyComparer = null)
    {
        if (transform == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(transform));
        if (keySelector == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(keySelector));
        if (dependenciesSelector == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dependenciesSelector));

        dataflowBlockOptions =
            dataflowBlockOptions ?? new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions();
        keyComparer = keyComparer ?? EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default;

        _items = new Dictionary<TKey, Item>(keyComparer);

        _inputBlock = new ActionBlock<TInput>(async input =>
        {
            var key = keySelector(input);
            var dependencyKeys = dependenciesSelector(input);
            bool isReadyForProcessing = true;
            Item item;
            lock (_locker)
            {
                if (!_items.TryGetValue(key, out item))
                {
                    item = new Item(key);
                    _items.Add(key, item);
                }
                if (item.HasInput)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException($"Duplicate key ({key}).");
                item.Input = input;
                item.HasInput = true;

                if (dependencyKeys != null && dependencyKeys.Count > 0)
                {
                    item.Dependencies = new HashSet<Item>();
                    foreach (var dependencyKey in dependencyKeys)
                    {
                        if (!_items.TryGetValue(dependencyKey, out var dependency))
                        {
                            dependency = new Item(dependencyKey);
                            _items.Add(dependencyKey, dependency);
                        }
                        if (!dependency.IsCompleted)
                        {
                            item.Dependencies.Add(dependency);
                            if (dependency.Dependents == null)
                                dependency.Dependents = new HashSet<Item>();
                            dependency.Dependents.Add(item);
                        }
                    }
                    isReadyForProcessing = item.Dependencies.Count == 0;
                }
                if (isReadyForProcessing) _pendingCount++;
            }
            if (isReadyForProcessing)
            {
                await _transformBlock.SendAsync(item);
            }
        }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
        {
            CancellationToken = dataflowBlockOptions.CancellationToken,
            BoundedCapacity = 1
        });

        var middleBuffer = new BufferBlock<Item>(new DataflowBlockOptions()
        {
            CancellationToken = dataflowBlockOptions.CancellationToken,
            BoundedCapacity = DataflowBlockOptions.Unbounded
        });

        _transformBlock = new TransformBlock<Item, TOutput>(async item =>
        {
            try
            {
                TInput input;
                lock (_locker)
                {
                    Debug.Assert(item.HasInput && !item.IsCompleted);
                    input = item.Input;
                }
                var result = await transform(input).ConfigureAwait(false);
                lock (_locker)
                {
                    item.IsCompleted = true;
                    if (item.Dependents != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var dependent in item.Dependents)
                        {
                            Debug.Assert(dependent.Dependencies != null);
                            var removed = dependent.Dependencies.Remove(item);
                            Debug.Assert(removed);
                            if (dependent.HasInput
                                && dependent.Dependencies.Count == 0)
                            {
                                middleBuffer.Post(dependent);
                                _pendingCount++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    item.Input = default; // Cleanup
                    item.Dependencies = null;
                    item.Dependents = null;
                }
                return result;
            }
            finally
            {
                lock (_locker)
                {
                    _pendingCount--;
                    if (_pendingCount == 0) middleBuffer.Complete();
                }
            }
        }, dataflowBlockOptions);

        middleBuffer.LinkTo(_transformBlock);

        PropagateCompletion(_inputBlock, middleBuffer,
            condition: () => { lock (_locker) return --_pendingCount == 0; });
        PropagateCompletion(middleBuffer, _transformBlock);
        PropagateFailure(_transformBlock, middleBuffer);
        PropagateFailure(_transformBlock, _inputBlock);
    }

    // Constructor with synchronous lambda
    public DependencyTransformBlock(
        Func<TInput, TOutput> transform,
        Func<TInput, TKey> keySelector,
        Func<TInput, IReadOnlyCollection<TKey>> dependenciesSelector,
        ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions dataflowBlockOptions = null,
        IEqualityComparer<TKey> keyComparer = null) : this(
            input => Task.FromResult(transform(input)),
            keySelector, dependenciesSelector, dataflowBlockOptions, keyComparer)
    {
        if (transform == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(transform));
    }

    public TInput[] Unprocessed
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_locker) return _items.Values
                .Where(item => item.HasInput && !item.IsCompleted)
                .Select(item => item.Input)
                .ToArray();
        }
    }

    public Task Completion => _transformBlock.Completion;
    public void Complete() => _inputBlock.Complete();
    void IDataflowBlock.Fault(Exception ex) => _inputBlock.Fault(ex);

    DataflowMessageStatus ITargetBlock<TInput>.OfferMessage(
        DataflowMessageHeader header, TInput value, ISourceBlock<TInput> source,
        bool consumeToAccept)
    {
        return _inputBlock.OfferMessage(header, value, source, consumeToAccept);
    }

    TOutput ISourceBlock<TOutput>.ConsumeMessage(DataflowMessageHeader header,
        ITargetBlock<TOutput> target, out bool messageConsumed)
    {
        return _transformBlock.ConsumeMessage(header, target, out messageConsumed);
    }

    bool ISourceBlock<TOutput>.ReserveMessage(DataflowMessageHeader header,
        ITargetBlock<TOutput> target)
    {
        return _transformBlock.ReserveMessage(header, target);
    }

    void ISourceBlock<TOutput>.ReleaseReservation(DataflowMessageHeader header,
        ITargetBlock<TOutput> target)
    {
        _transformBlock.ReleaseReservation(header, target);
    }

    public IDisposable LinkTo(ITargetBlock<TOutput> target,
        DataflowLinkOptions linkOptions)
    {
        return _transformBlock.LinkTo(target, linkOptions);
    }

    private async void PropagateCompletion(IDataflowBlock source,
        IDataflowBlock target, Func<bool> condition = null)
    {
        try { await source.Completion.ConfigureAwait(false); } catch { }
        if (source.Completion.IsFaulted)
            target.Fault(source.Completion.Exception.InnerException);
        else
            if (condition == null || condition()) target.Complete();
    }

    private async void PropagateFailure(IDataflowBlock source,
        IDataflowBlock target)
    {
        try { await source.Completion.ConfigureAwait(false); } catch { }
        if (source.Completion.IsFaulted)
            target.Fault(source.Completion.Exception.InnerException);
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
var block = new DependencyTransformBlock<Item, string, Item>(item =>
{
    DoWork(item);
    return item;
},
keySelector: item => item.Name,
dependenciesSelector: item => item.DependsOn,
new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount
},
keyComparer: StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

//...

block.LinkTo(DataflowBlock.NullTarget<Item>());
```

In this example the block is linked to a [`NullTarget`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblock.nulltarget) in order to discard its output, so that it becomes essentially an `ActionBlock` equivalent.