# Use async Action in ActionBlock without deadlock

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I want to use an `ActionBlock` to asynchronously process messages received via a `TcpClient`.
My problem is, that I sometimes have to wait for data from other messages. If I just use await with a `TaskCompletionSource` I run into a deadlock.
e.g.:

```
TaskCompletionSource tcs = new();
ActionBlock<int> actionBlock = new(async n =>
{
    if (n == 1)
    {
        tcs.SetResult();
    }
    else
    {
        await tcs.Task;
    }
});
await actionBlock.SendAsync(0);
await Task.Delay(10);
await actionBlock.SendAsync(1);
await tcs.Task;
```

The last line will never finish since the second message is never processed.
I'm aware, that I could increase the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` value.
But is there any way to tell the `ActionBlock` to process the next message, if the current action awaits data?

Comment: This may give you some ideas: [TPL DataFlow Queue with Postponement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64380946/tpl-dataflow-queue-with-postponement/)

Comment: Do you know if a message needs to be queued before you process it? whats the criteria, how do you determine that. The easiest approach (just like any message/service bus), is to split up the messages into different pipes and possibly a join block (depending on the specifics). If you knew this information beforehand its as easy as a linkto predicate. If you need to figure this out in flight, you would just create a preprocessor. If none of this is applicable. You might want to look at implementing your own block